# Can OIDC (Open ID Connect) be used to authenticate in a native app withoud a browser?

Tags: authentication, oauth, openid-connect

Is it possible to authenticate a user and receive an access token from an OIDC identity provider without leaving the application and using a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the answer is "no", but there are some buts and caveats.

OAuth and OpenID Connect were designed with the browser in mind. Letting the flows go through a browser has two important security implications for the whole framework:

1. At some point in an OAuth/OIDC flow, the user is redirected to a given redirect URI with the authorization code. When the redirect is handled by a browser, we (as OAuth users) depend on the browser to handle it properly. I.e. to properly resolve the redirect URI using DNS, so that the authorization code is returned to the correct entity. If the flow did not go through the browser you would have to trust the application provider to properly resolve the redirect. This could lead to malicious apps impersonating legitimate clients as these apps would receive the authorization code back, instead of the legitimate app.
2. The second feature is important when you have a third-party app talking to an OAuth/OIDC server. Thanks to OAuth/OIDC users do not share their passwords with third-party apps. Users are always redirected to the provider in a browser (e.g. to Google) and enter their password there. So the app never gets the user's password. If you dropped the browser, that would not be possible. The app would have access to the user's password. In a first-party setup, this is not a problem, because you keep the password anyway.

So you see that it's not recommended to skip using the browser. You can, however, use mobile features to implement an OAuth/OIDC flow so that the user never leaves your app. You don't have to open a full browser, instead, you can open a browser tab inside your application. The feature is called a `Chrome custom tab` in Android and `SFSafariViewController` in iOS.

There is another option, but I need to post a disclaimer: currently, I am an employee of Curity and I will mention our own solutions. At Curity, we develop an OAuth authorization server that has a feature called Hypermedia Authentication API (HAAPI) that allows you to achieve what you mention — you can run an OAuth/OIDC flow using just a JSON-based API, directly from a mobile app. We added some security features to solve the problems mentioned above. I'm not posting any links as you can Google information on HAAPI quite easily. if you find it interesting. Note that this feature requires a paid version of the Curity Identity Server.